# bash script - how to check if any directory that starts with exists

Tags: bash, macos

I've been trying to write a script:

```
EFIDIR=/Volumes/EFI
KEXTDEST=$EFIDIR/EFI/CLOVER/kexts/Other

if [[ -d $EFIDIR/EFI/CLOVER/kexts/10.* ]]; then
    echo "Directory found."
    if [[ -d $EFIDIR/EFI/CLOVER/kexts/10.*/*.kext ]]; then
        echo "Kext(s) found."
        cp -R $EFIDIR/EFI/CLOVER/kexts/10.*/*.kext $KEXTDEST
    fi
    rm -R $EFIDIR/EFI/CLOVER/kexts/10.*
fi
```

I want to check whether any folder that starts with "10." (can be 10.10, 10.11... etc) exist then if any of those folders contains a folder that ends with (.kext) exists... copy to the destination folder.

How to write it the right way?

Thanks.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/100876

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
EFIDIR=/Volumes/EFI
KEXTDEST=$EFIDIR/EFI/CLOVER/kexts/Other

for each in $(find $EFIDIR/EFI/CLOVER/kexts/ -name "10.*" -type d); do
    echo "Directory found."
    for innerdir in $(find $each -name "*.kext" -type d); do
        echo "Kext(s) found."
        cp -R $innerdir $KEXTDEST
    done
    rm -R $each
done
```

`find $EFIDIR/EFI/CLOVER/kexts/ -name "10.*" -type d` will look for directories (`-type d`) starting with name `10.*` in `$EFIDIR/EFI/CLOVER/kexts` and if found will loop through every one in the `for` loop.

The inner `for` loop looks for directories starting with name `*.kext` .